# Sonarqube Webapp did not start

Tags: sonarqube

I am installing SN5.5 using PostgreSQL9.5 under Windows. Unfortunately, I am hitting error "Webapp did not start".

Below is the full stack trace. I think I got the error first at line "Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener"

```
2016.05.19 18:10:59 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.19 18:10:59 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.05.19 18:11:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.5 / 5773a4aab0ef6c0de79d3038e82f8a051049d6d0
2016.05.19 18:11:00 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
2016.05.19 18:11:01 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.
2016.05.19 18:11:01 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016.05.19 18:11:01 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016.05.19 18:11:01 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2016.05.19 18:11:01 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.19 18:11:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.05.19 18:11:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.05.19 18:11:01 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:48) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:69) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
2016.05.19 18:11:01 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.19 18:11:02 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.19 18:11:02 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.19 18:11:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2016.05.19 18:11:03 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2016.05.19 18:11:03 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2016.05.19 18:11:03 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1463652653150] stopping ...
2016.05.19 18:11:03 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1463652653150] stopped
2016.05.19 18:11:03 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1463652653150] closing ...
2016.05.19 18:11:03 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1463652653150] closed
2016.05.19 18:11:04 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: `org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.`

Comment: Which SonarQube version were you previously using with this database ?

Answer (score 4):

```
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.
```

This log means than you're trying to upgrade to a too recent version. You should first upgrade to the nearest LTS version (probably 4.5.X), then you'll be able to upgrade to 5.5.

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading for more information about the upgrade strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding below properties in wrapper.conf file. It did the trick for me.

```
# Java Additional Parameter
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=160m
wrapper.java.additional.3=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djruby.management.enabled=false
# Maximum amount of memory of Java VM
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Xmx2048M
```