# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener

Tags: oracle11g, sonarqube-5.5

I downloaded SonarQube 5.5 with fresh database on oracle 11g and also configured the sonar.properties file. I am unable to start the server and getting the error as shown below:

```
2016.05.27 09:36:45 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.05.27 09:36:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.5 / 5773a4aab0ef6c0de79d3038e82f8a051049d6d0
2016.05.27 09:36:46 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.101.18.252:1522:orcl1
2016.05.27 09:36:48 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class  org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.
2016.05.27 09:36:48 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016.05.27 09:36:48 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016.05.27 09:36:48 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016.05.27 09:36:48 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:327)
2016.05.27 09:36:48 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.27 09:36:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.05.27 09:36:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.05.27 09:36:48 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:48) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.5.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:69) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
2016.05.27 09:36:48 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.27 09:36:49 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.27 09:36:49 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.27 09:36:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2016.05.27 15:06:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2016.05.27 15:06:50 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2016.05.27 15:06:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464341797936] stopping ...
2016.05.27 15:06:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464341797936] stopped
2016.05.27 15:06:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464341797936] closing ...
2016.05.27 15:06:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1464341797936] closed
2016.05.27 15:06:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I am not able to understand which version need to upgrade.

Thank you for help in advance !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonarqube Webapp did not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336739/sonarqube-webapp-did-not-start)

Comment: I downloaded fresh sonarqube 5.5 version. why should I downgrade the setup first?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have this error see your database, it is because it has data when you error.

Try:

```
delete your database sonar;
drop database sonar;
redo
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved with fresh and clean the database and also delete the logs and data folder before running the first instance.